# Lindbladian Acting Simultaneously on Density Matrix and Operator

Tags: quantum-mechanics, hilbert-space, quantum-optics, density-operator

It is known that Lindblad operator acting on density matrix explicitly would be written as:

$$
    \tilde{\mathcal{L}}\rho=-\frac{i}{\hbar}[H_0,\rho]-\mathcal{L}\rho=-\frac{i}{\hbar}[H_0,\rho]-(X^{\dagger}X\rho + \rho X^{\dagger}X -2 X\rho X^{\dagger})
$$

and that for a Heisenberg operator $A$ we can write :

$$
    \tilde{\mathcal{L}}A=\frac{i}{\hbar}[H_0,A]+\mathcal{L}A=\frac{i}{\hbar}[H_0,A]-(X^{\dagger}XA + A X^{\dagger}X -2 X^{\dagger}A X)
$$

If I wanted to write Lindbladian for the operator and density matrix together, how could I proceed, and would it be even possible? Namely, how could one write something like

$$
    \tilde{\mathcal{L}}[A\rho]?
$$

Comment: That doesn't make any sense. Which sense would it make? If you want to compute the expectation value at some time, you can either evolve A or rho, but not both.  Note that the two L-tildes you write are not at all the same object, and you should better use different notation.

Comment: To rephrase Norberts point, you may work in the Schroedinger picture *or* the Heisenberg picture, but not both simaltaneously. In the former case use your first equation, and operators do not evolve, in the latter case use your second equation and $\rho$ does not evolve.

Comment: I see your point. But how about Interaction picture? There both density matrix and interaction Hamiltonian evolve in time. Which would be the case when Lindblad terms are zero in my question.